# Deepl API TranslateDocumentAsync cannot convert from FileStream to FileInfo C# librabry

Tags: c#, file, filestream, deepl

I use the C# library to connect to the DeepL API. According to the documentation, you can use the `TranslateDocumentAsync` method for document translation. This method should be able to accept the `FileInfo` and `Stream` parameters.

```
await _translator.TranslateDocumentAsync(
      sourceFileStream,
      targetFileStream,
      "DE",
      "FR");
```

However, when I transfer a file that I have saved as a `FileStream`, I always get the error

> Cannot convert from System.IO.FileStream to System.IO.FileInfo

How can I pass a Stream/FileStream as a parameter?

Comment: *"This method should be able to accept the FileInfo and Stream parameters"* What makes you think that? The error message suggests otherwise.

Comment: The official documentation makes me think that. https://github.com/DeepLcom/deepl-dotnet#translating-documents.
It says "To translate documents, call TranslateDocumentAsync() with the input and output files as either FileInfo or Stream objects".

Comment: Looks like those overloads take different parameters, perhaps you should look at them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [overload accepting](https://github.com/DeepLcom/deepl-dotnet/blob/main/DeepL/Translator.cs#L111) `Stream` has an additional second argument: `string inputFilename`. This is used to tell the DeepL API the input file type; actually the input file extension is sufficient, for example `".pdf"`.

The description in the readme is misleading. I'm a maintainer, so I'll correct the readme description.